# Ion range slider not working with small range values angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create the ion slider dynamically in angular 
4. One Ion range slider handle does not appear if the range is very small and it is not sliding.
For example: min =0 and max =0.13 step = 0.1.
Below is the code for range slider:

```
$(".sliderElement5").ionRangeSlider({
        type: "double",
        steps: 0.1,
        grid: true,
        from_shadow: true,
        to_shadow: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 0.13,
        from:0,
        to: 0.13,
        from_min: 0,
        from_max: 0.13,
        to_min: 0,
        to_max: 0.13,

        })
```